Implementing Dependency Injection in Next.js with Tsyringe and Playwright: Resolving Unregistered Dependency Error
I would like to accomplish the following using Next.js:

Implement Dependency Injection (DI) using tsyringe.
For normal requests, inject the usual code and execute it.
When testing with playwright, inject the test code and execute it.

Currently, I have the following code:
///// next.config.js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    instrumentationHook: true,
  },
}

///// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  }
}

///// src/instrumentation.ts
import 'reflect-metadata'

export async function register() {
  if (process.env['NEXT_RUNTIME'] === 'nodejs') {
    await import('./container')
  }
}


///// src/container.ts
import 'reflect-metadata'
import { container } from 'tsyringe'
import { User } from './components/user'

container.register('IUser', { useClass: User })


///// src/components/user.ts
import { injectable } from 'tsyringe'

@injectable()
export class User implements IUser {
  public name: string | undefined | null
  protected age: number | undefined | null

  init(): void {
    console.log('User initialized')
    this.name = 'John Doe'
    this.age = 30
  }

  public setAge(age: number): void {
    this.age = age
  }
  public getAge(): number | undefined | null {
    return this.age
  }
}


///// src/components/user-mock.ts
import { injectable } from 'tsyringe'
import { User } from './user'

@injectable()
export class UserMock extends User {
  init(): void {
    console.log('User Mock initialized')
    this.name = 'Test User'
  }
}


///// src/pages/di.tsx
import { User } from '@/components/user'
import { container } from 'tsyringe'

export default function Di() {
  const user = container.resolve<User>('IUser')
  user.init()

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        name: <span id="user-name">{user.name}</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        age: <span id="user-age">{user.getAge()}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

And I have created and executed the following test code:
///// tests/example.spec.ts
import 'reflect-metadata'
import { User } from '@/components/user'
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test'
import { container } from 'tsyringe'
import { UserMock } from '@/components/user-mock'

test('Test-sample', async ({ page }) => {
  const mock = new UserMock()
  mock.setAge(50)
  container.register('IUser', { useValue: mock })
  // Start from the index page (the baseURL is set via the webServer in the playwright.config.ts)
  await page.goto('/di')

  await expect(page.locator('#user-age')).toContainText('50')
})

However, I encountered the following error:
///// di.tsx. 
const user = container.resolve<User>('IUser')
// → Error: Attempted to resolve unregistered dependency token: "IUser"

I haven't been able to find many sample codes that use Next.js, tsyringe, and playwright together. If possible, I would greatly appreciate your guidance.
If using other DI or testing libraries can solve the issue, there is no problem in using other libraries.

React (nextjs) is inherently functional. DI isn’t actually that much different than functional anyway. In DI you “inject” depdencies into a container and then pull them out, in functional you “inject” them by passsing them as arguments. React has an additional DI mechanism built in (other than passing arguments) called Context - which provides values to things lower in the tree - fundamentally the same as DI. I know this doesn’t answer your question, but your life will be much easier if you don’t use traditional OOP DI in react/nextjs and stick to passing arguments and using Context Providers

@AdamJenkins Except that the Context API is not available for Nextjs' Server components, which are the default.
